# Visual Studio 2019 - Publish Profile problem

Tags: visual-studio, publish-profiles, pubxml

Seems like the most recent update in visual studio 2019 changed something that forces you to pick a publish profile before publishing a file.  For instance, I have a web developer who often publishes .cshtml files to a website - we only have one publish profile which used to work fine, you could publish no problem and it was never an issue.  Now in the most recent 16.9 visual studio update you have to actually go to the Web Publish Activity window, select the *single* item in the list to even get the ability to publish.  I get that they did that as a safety measure, but it doesn't make any sense to force the user to pick the only item in the list before they can publish.

Previous versions of Visual Studio let you set a default publish profile, but they've since taken that ability away (as far as I can tell).

Does anybody have a good solution\workaround for this - should never have to select a Publish profile if you only have one.

Comment: I'm getting similar with VS2022.
It often changes to another profile or just deselects them. When I'm just tweaking views or republishing built client side files, it often just doesn't happen or publishes them somewhere else cos it's changed profile randomly.
I keep having to open the publish the web project window, then the web publish window will update to match the selected profile. Damned annoying when you want to publish a single file.